# always allocates and returns a new instance of resource class System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.Internal.Disposables

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, tpl-dataflow, coverity

> alloc_fn: Method
> LinkTo<X.Offers.Core.DataFlow.RefreshOfferMatching.RefreshUsersOffersContext>
> always allocates and returns a new instance of the resource class
> System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.Internal.Disposables/Disposable`3.
> (#1 of 1): Resource leak (RESOURCE_LEAK)
> 2. leaked_resource: Ignoring resource created by this._buffer.LinkTo(this._sender) leaks it.

```cs
private RefreshUsersOffersDataFlow() {
  try {
    
    _buffer = new BufferBlock<RefreshUsersOffersContext>(
        new DataflowBlockOptions{BoundedCapacity = 10000});
    var asyncSendFunc = new Func < RefreshUsersOffersContext,
        Task(RefreshUsersOffers);
    _sender = new ActionBlock<RefreshUsersOffersContext>(
        asyncSendFunc,
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8});
   _buffer.LinkTo(_sender);
    // Set completion order (we aren't really completing)
    _buffer.Completion.ContinueWith(t => _sender.Complete());
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    PzEvents.CaptureSystemEvent(
        $"{nameof(RefreshUsers)}_Initialization_Exception", ex);
  }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why we get this error, and how to resolve this sort of issue for Coverity?

Comment: An ActionBlock already has an input buffer. `_buffer` isn't needed. As for `ContinueWith` it's not needed either, if you pass the `PropagateCompletion` option to `LinkTo`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a false positive that can be safely ignored.

The code line in question is:

```
_buffer.LinkTo(_sender);
```

The [`BufferBlock<T>.LinkTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.bufferblock-1.linkto?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-dataflow-bufferblock-1-linkto(system-threading-tasks-dataflow-itargetblock((-0))-system-threading-tasks-dataflow-dataflowlinkoptions)) method returns an [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-6.0), which is normally used to release resources.  Coverity evidently knows this and complains that you are not disposing of the resource here, which would ordinarily be a bug.

But `BufferBlock<T>.LinkTo` is a special case, as it returns:

> An IDisposable that, upon calling Dispose, will unlink the source from the target.

That is, this `IDisposable` does *not* release resources, but instead just changes the Task Parallel Library (TPL) block network structure.  Therefore it does not need to be called.

As further evidence of the lack of necessity to dispose, observe that the first Microsoft tutorial that uses it, [Walkthrough: Creating a Dataflow Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline), calls `LinkTo` several times without using `Dispose`.  In fact, I couldn't find *any* Microsoft example that uses `Dispose` on the result of `LinkTo`.  Even the tutorial [How to: Unlink Dataflow Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-unlink-dataflow-blocks) does not use `Dispose`, but instead uses the `MaxMessages` option to unlink implicitly.

I did find a section in [Concurrency in C# Cookbook](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/concurrency-in-c/9781491906675/) by Stephen Cleary, specifically [4.3 Unlinking Blocks](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/concurrency-in-c/9781491906675/ch04.html#recipe-dataflow-unlinking), that describes unlinking as "an advanced scenario and is hardly ever needed", and gives a code example using `Dispose` this way.  (This is after a few previous examples that ignore the `LinkTo` return value.)  This reinforces the conclusion that `Dispose` is not needed here.

It is unfortunate that Microsoft chose to overload `IDisposable` this way, as it is confusing to both programmers and tools.

You might want to report this back to Coverity so they can fix the tool.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is a false positive, but the code has other problems.

First of all, `_buffer` isn't needed at all. `ActionBlock<T>` already has an input buffer, jut like most blocks. The input buffer's BoundedCapacity can be set through the `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions` parameter:

```
var blockOptions=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { 
    BoundedCapacity = 100 ,
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 
};
_sender = new ActionBlock<RefreshUsersOffersContext>(MyActualFunction,blockOptions);

...
async Task MyActualFunction(RefreshUsersOffersContext context)
{
...
}
```

If you don't set a BoundedCapacity the input buffer can grow indefinitely.

In any case, if there's no capacity limit or you don't want to await until the block can accept input, you can use `Post` instead of `SendAsync`:

```
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
   _block.Post(i);
}
```

Second, the `ContinueWith` call isn't needed to propagate completion. The correct way is to pass [PropagateCompletion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions.propagatecompletion?view=net-6.0) through `DataflowLinkOptions :

```
var linkOptions=new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true};

_head.LinkTo(_transform,linkOptions);
_transform.LinkTo(_tail,linkOptions);
```

This allows calling `Complete()` on the head block and awaiting until all messages are processed by awaiting on the tail:

```
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
   await _head.SendAsync(i);
}
_head.Complete();
await _tail.Completion;
```

Finally, a `BoundedCapacity` of 100000 is too big. By default, the input buffer has no upper bound so there's no reason to set such a large bound.

`BoundedCapacity` is used to *prevent* caching a lot of items in memory if the downstream pipeline blocks can't handle them. When a block's input buffer is full upstream blocks are forced to pause. This way, the entire pipeline is throttled.

Imagine having a pipeline that accepts URLs as input, downloads some files, parses them and inserts the results into a database. Without `BoundedCapacity` and eg a slow database, the download block would keep making HTTP requests that the parsers and database can't handle. All these would get cached in memory until the application crashed, or froze due to excessive garbage collection.